Which FIDE federations has never sent a women's team to the Chess Olympiads
The 2024 Olympiad teams were announced some time ago, and this year there are 184 registered federations in the Women’s section.
Which FIDE federations have never sent a women’s team to the Chess Olympiads, including this year?
